# About on Stack Exchange has bad margin from the left on smaller screens

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

On smaller screens, such as a Samsung Galaxy S5 (1080 x 1920 in portrait mode), at least with Chrome, the content of the SE about page extends past the left edge of the screen:

1. Go to https://stackexchange.com/about
2. You'll see the very left part is eaten.

   > [image]

Comment: No repro on maximized Chrome 41.0.2272.101, Windows 7 on 1680x1050

Comment: @AndrewT. I *think* (correct me if I'm wrong) he means when the window is not wide enough. If you narrow the window, the top-bar droplist and logo are left aligned, but the page content hangs off the left even when the browser's horizontal scrollbar is pegged left.

Comment: No, I do not see anything eaten and your HUGE arrows (?) really don't help to emphasize the problem, they just cause a big distraction.

Comment: @JasonC ha, saw what you meant. In such case it's [tag:status-declined], since 1024 pixels are the minimum supported screen width. Users with less than that can enjoy the mobile theme and/or official apps.

Comment: @Sha I think that 1920 is more than 1024 :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Fwiw, S5 is 1080 (> 1024) wide in portrait mode. 1080x1920.

Comment: @nicael Is this the mobile or desktop version of the site?

Comment: @JasonC stackexchange.com doesn't have mobile version.